# Extrapolation of expected value in multivariate regression

Tags: machine-learning, extrapolation

Consider a random variables $Y, X, Z$. Denote by $f$ a function of the expectation of $Y$: $ f(x,z) = \mathbb{E} [Y\mid X=x, Z=z]$.  Define a marginal function $$g(x) = \mathbb{E} [Y\mid X=x] = \int f(x,z)dF_Z(z).$$

Given an iid sample from $(Y,X,Z)$ of size $n$, we can estimate $f$ by many different machine learning methods. My question relates to the best technique to extrapolate function $f$ or $g$ outside of observed values.

As for the function $g$, my idea would be to use simply the largest $k<<n$ values and use linear model on them to extrapolate linearly function $g$ outside of the support. Or even better, put weights on all values, putting much more weight on large values and negligable weight on small values. Do you have some reference for this?

If $f$ is multivariate, how can we do this somehow optimally?

[[image: Red points are data, black is the function <span class=]$g$, we want to estimate the black line outside of support." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xonzk.png)

Comment: The first thing to be acknowledged here is that the data don't give you information to check whether whatever is done is any good. This means that you can't have a generally good recommendation. The first thing I'd ask is whether there is subject matter information that could help, and whether the pattern observed in the data you have reveals any pattern such as general linearity, periodicity etc.

Comment: You often find more complicated models behave peculiarly when extrapolating beyond known data.

Comment: What if we want to extrapolate linearly? I.e, we assume that the function is linear in the limit (but can behave wildly in the body, as in the picture). Are there some known methods to fit a linear model only on the tail?